# Sort numbers values - separated by a dot or any other separator character - Sort versions values in RHEL5

Tags: linux, bash, sorting, numbers, versions

Linux RHEL5 machine

How can I sort the following input to get `1.0.0.1019` in `latest` variable? Tried `-t`, `-k` and `-n` but it didn't help or may be I'm missing something.

```
$ echo '1.0.0
1.0.0.1018
1.0.0.1019
1.0.0.1019
1.0.0.7' | sort -u
```

Comment: `-V` gave me: sort: `invalid option -- V`. Seems like on RHEL6 it works.

Comment: `sort -t. -k 1,1n -k 2,2n -k 3,3n -k 4,4n ` did it in RHEL5

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. Please show your code. Since Stack Overflow hides the Close reason from you: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).*

Answer (score 2):

Could you please try following and let me know if this helps(tested with GNU `sort`):

```
echo "1.0.0
1.0.0.1018
1.0.0.1019
1.0.0.1019
1.0.0.7" | sort --version-sort --field-separator=. --key=4 -r
```

Above will give `1019` in first place(latest one) in case you want it to last place then remove `-r` in above code please.

Comment: that was a really good one !

Answer (score -1):

`sort -n -t. -k1,4`

Sort the input numerically.
Fields are separated by '.'
Only use the first four fields, in that order.

Comment: No, I just tested it is not giving expected results see this once https://stackoverflow.com/a/50691470/5866580

Comment: Oops, I see the problem. My apologies.